# Install Boost specific modules from GitHub

Tags: git, boost, github, cmake, git-submodules

I'm working on a script that clones [Boost official repository](https://github.com/boostorg/boost) and init only the modules I need.

I read [git submodule man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), and found a way to update only some modules. I don't even need to compile because I'm only using [multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

```
git clone -b boost-1.60.0 https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git boost
cd boost
git submodule update --init libs/multi_index/ tools/build
```

But I would like to improve my `git submodule update` command by using module names (e.g. `multi_index` found in `.gitsubmodules`) instead of path (e.g. `libs\multi_index`)

How can I achieve that ?

Also, when I want to use that setup, `boost/version.hpp` is missing.
I executed `boostrap.sh` and `./b2 --with-multi_index` but it replied with `error: wrong library name 'multi_index' in the --with-<library> option.`

How can I generate `boost/version.hpp` that `CMake` `find_package(Boost REQUIRED)` requires ?

> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:699 (file):
>     file STRINGS file
>     "/home/leflou/PROJECTS/tradingsuite/FinancialMarket/Server/boost/libs/boost/version.hpp"
>     cannot be read.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     FinancialMarket/Server/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, whenever a library is updated, you need to `./b2 headers` in the main repo, so all the symlinks to the library headers get updated in the `boost/` subdirectory.

You seem to be forgetting that Multi Index relies on a host of other boost libraries - which need to be synchronized in the updates.

E.g. BMI uses MPL, tuple, and many others:

```
 60 boost/mpl
 56 boost/config.hpp
 39 boost/type_traits
 32 boost/detail
 29 boost/preprocessor
 17 boost/serialization
 11 boost/noncopyable.hpp
 10 boost/move
  7 boost/utility
  7 boost/tuple
  6 boost/static_assert.hpp
  5 boost/throw_exception.hpp
  5 boost/call_traits.hpp
  4 boost/operators.hpp
  4 boost/foreach_fwd.hpp
  4 boost/bind.hpp
  4 boost/archive (optional)
  3 boost/iterator
  2 boost/ref.hpp
  2 boost/limits.hpp
  2 boost/functional (for `hash`)
  2 boost/assert.hpp
  1 boost/integer
```

You should be looking at **[BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html)** to do the right extraction